# HMAC-SHA1 in bash

Tags: bash, hmacsha1

Is there a bash script available to generate a **HMAC-SHA1** hash?

The equivalent of the following PHP code:

```
hash_hmac("sha1", "value", "key", TRUE);
```

Parameters

```
true : When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase hexits.
```

Thanks.

see [HMAC-SHA1 in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285059/hmac-sha1-in-bash)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HMAC-SHA1 in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285059/hmac-sha1-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` itself, no, it can do a lot of stuff but it also knows when to rely on external tools.

For example, the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) provides a Python implementation which `bash` can call to do the grunt work for HMAC_MD5, repeated below to make this answer self-contained:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from hashlib import md5 
trans_5C = "".join(chr(x ^ 0x5c) for x in xrange(256))
trans_36 = "".join(chr(x ^ 0x36) for x in xrange(256))
blocksize = md5().block_size

def hmac_md5(key, msg):
    if len(key) > blocksize:
        key = md5(key).digest()
    key += chr(0) * (blocksize - len(key))
    o_key_pad = key.translate(trans_5C)
    i_key_pad = key.translate(trans_36)
    return md5(o_key_pad + md5(i_key_pad + msg).digest())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = hmac_md5("key", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    print h.hexdigest()  # 80070713463e7749b90c2dc24911e275
```

(keeping in mind that Python also contains SHA1 stuff as well, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html) for details on how to use HMAC with the `hashlib.sha1()` constructor).

Or, if you want to run the exact same code as PHP does, you could try running it with `phpsh`, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520090/how-to-execute-php-code-from-the-command-line).